# How can one replace missing values in a column with values imputed from the same column?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to update missing values in a column, with median values calculated from the same column, by group. As an example, here is a reprex, based on the train.csv dataset from the Titanic data. What I want to do is update the missing values in the Age column by median age for groups defined by the Sex, Embarked and Pclass variables (I am saving these variables as factors before getting median age).

The only way I could think of doing this was to subset the missing data, fill in the missing age by the median age of the groups, and then `rbind` the result with the rest of the dataset.

```
    library(data.table)
    train <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nybbles/kaggle/master/train.csv")
    train[,sex := factor(sex)]
    train[,survived := factor(survived, labels = c("did not survive","survived"))]
    train[embarked == "",embarked := "S"]
    train[,embarked := factor(embarked,labels = c("Cherbourg","Queenstown","Southampton"))]
    train[,pclass := factor(pclass,ordered = T,levels = c(3,2,1))]

    train[is.na(age),.N] # 177 missing in age column
    age_imputed <- train[!is.na(age),.(age = median(age)),.(sex,embarked,pclass)] #Step 1
    age_missing <- train[is.na(age)] #Step 2
    train <- train[!is.na(age)] #Step 3
    age_missing[,age:=NULL] #Step 4
    age_missing <- age_imputed[age_missing,on = c("sex","embarked","pclass")] #Step 5
    train <- rbindlist(list(train,age_missing), use.names = TRUE)# Step 6
```

Instead, is there a 'faster' way to do this by reference, instead of subsetting the data? Subsetting and `rbind`ing the data seems unnecessarily manipulative and error-prone to me. I tried

```
train[,Age := ifelse(is.na(Age),age_imputed$Age[which(age_imputed$Sex == train$Sex & age_imputed$Embarked == train$Embarked & age_imputed$Pclass == train$Pclass)],
                     Age)]
```

as a potential solution, but kept coming up against various errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an update join with left table (`.SD`) being rows with NAs for `Age`:

```
train[is.na(Age), Age :=
    age_imputed[.SD, on=.(Sex, Embarked, Pclass), x.Age]
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @chinsoon12, your suggestion worked. Can you elaborate on your code a bit more? I have never seen the usage `x.Age`, what does that mean, and is that part of `data.table` syntax?